# prove that the given number is divisible by 3

Tags: number-theory

If there are two numbers x and y selected at the random (1,2,3 ......3n) such that x$^2$-y$^2$ is divisible by 3 . We have to find number of pair of x,y .

Itried as follows , but got stuck , can anyone help me[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(x+y)(x-y) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ Since there is no zero divisor on $\mathbb Z_3$, $x+y \equiv 0 \pmod 3 $or $x-y \equiv 0 \pmod 3 $ and then divides into some cases and division:

If $x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ then $ y\equiv 0 \pmod 3$

If $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ then $y \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ or $y \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

If $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ then $y \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ or $y \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

Comment: Can you please elaborate it

Comment: @user123733  I have detailed it much so the last answer is { (x,y) | (x = y = 0 mod 3) or (x  $\neq$ 0 and  y $\neq$ 0 mod 3) } .

Comment: and the count is ? ( ps : is the last line correct ? )

Comment: @igael oh dude, that's why "Hint:" there, the count is very easy, the number of pair satisfying first condition is n times n minus n. The number of pair ssc is 2 times n square minus 2 times n. And if pair ordered, it should be divided 2.

Comment: What do you mean by pr

Comment: ok Zack, I'm not familiar with the hints. ( ps : is the last line correct ? )

Comment: $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \implies x = 3k+2 $ if $x \equiv y \pmod 3$ then $y \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. Otherwise $x \equiv -y \pmod 3$ then y = 3(w-k)-2 = 3(w-k-1)+1 which means $y \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

Comment: It's a good hint. Just adjust the symmetry of the 2 last lines whatever your notations are.

Comment: For count why we have subtracted 2n and what do you mean by ordered pair

Comment: @user123733 ordered pair is (u,v) satisfying the condition and u<v.

Answer (score 1):

You can do $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)=3k$ and put $x+y=3k$ and $x-y=1$ so you get 
$$x=\frac{3k+1}{2}\\y=\frac{3k-1}{2}$$ It follows you need $3k$ be odd. This gives 
$$x=3m+2\\y=3m-1$$ You get 
$$(x,y)\in \{(5,2),(8,5),....(a,b)\}$$ where $(a,b)$ is the last couple which is determined by $2+3m\lt 3n\Rightarrow m\lt \frac{3n-2}{3}$ so $m=[\frac{3n-2}{3}]$ the integer part or the floor function of $\frac{3n-2}{3}$. You have $m=n-1$ hence $$(a,b)=(3n-1,3n-4)$$